# How do I add more scopes in Azure B2C user flow?

Tags: asp.net, azure, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have a User Flow configured in Azure B2C.

When I check the .well-known/openid-configuration I have only 'openid' in the scopes_supported.

Can I add other scopes, like profile or offline_access?

```
{
  "issuer": "https://***.b2clogin.com/tfp/********-ad73-4362-a92f-302dc508e063/b2c_1_***/v2.0/",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://***.b2clogin.com/***.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_***/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "https://***.b2clogin.com/***.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_***/oauth2/v2.0/token",
  "end_session_endpoint": "https://***.b2clogin.com/***.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_***/oauth2/v2.0/logout",
  "jwks_uri": "https://***.b2clogin.com/***.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_***/discovery/v2.0/keys",
  "response_modes_supported": [
    "query",
    "fragment",
    "form_post"
  ],
  "response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token",
    "id_token",
    "id_token token",
    "token",
    "token id_token"
  ],
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "pairwise"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ],
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_post",
    "client_secret_basic"
  ],
  "claims_supported": [
    "idp",
    "oid",
    "sub",
    "emails",
    "name",
    "newUser",
    "idp_access_token",
    "tfp",
    "iss",
    "iat",
    "exp",
    "aud",
    "acr",
    "nonce",
    "auth_time"
  ]
}
```

My main issue is that I cannot get user info. Not sure if it's related to the missing profile scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: Azure AD B2C Application only supports **`openid`** and **`offline_access`** delegated permissions only. Hence, it's not possible to add extra scopes to the Application.

[image]

I created an **Azure AD B2C Application and added API permissions** like below:

[image]

I created a Sign up and sign in User flow and added **Application claims**:

> Based on the requirement, you can select the Application claims.

[image]

I run the **user flow and signed-in** with the user like below:

[image]

**ID Token got generated successfully with user information**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, after all, it turned out, I cannot get the user info because there is no UserInfo endpoint in B2C user flow. The client I'm using is expecting the values from this endpoint,  so I guess I need to get it from the id_token instead.