# azure ad b2c; after mobile log in: the token returned does not include an access token, but a token Id

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to login to my azure b2c from my mobile app.
The log in portal i created starts up and I can create a user or log in,
once im done i am being returned data that I can see from my IDE:

[image]

So, I am getting an IdToken back, which I can even decode. to show my username and stuff, but no access token is granted.

I have no clue why this is.

I set up all my constants:

```
public static readonly string ClientId = "asd"; 
    public static readonly string[] Scopes = { "openid", "offline_access" };
    // The next code to add B2C
    public static readonly string TenantName = "skillbasedauth";
    public static readonly string TenantId = $"{TenantName}.onmicrosoft.com";
    public static readonly string SignInPolicy = "B2C_1_Client";
    public static readonly string AuthorityBase = $"https://{TenantName}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{TenantId}/";
    public static readonly string AuthoritySignIn = $"{AuthorityBase}{SignInPolicy}";
    public static readonly string IosKeychainSecurityGroups = "com.microsoft.adalcache";
```

I also set the scopes:

[image]

I set the return URL

[image]

is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD B2C Application** like below:

[image]

Granted **API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated **access token** by using below parameters like below:

```json
https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signinsignup/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:xxxx
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:openid offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

Only **ID and refresh tokens** got generated but not access token like below:

[image]

Hence, to get the **access token with ID and refresh tokens**, Expose an API and add scope like below:

[image]

Now while generating the add **scope** as `https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/test.read openid offline_access` to get access token too.

[image]

When decoded the **access token, scopes are displayed**:

[image]

Comment: i did this exactly like you do, but as soon as I create any scope other then my own I get "the scope files.read provided in the request is not supported"

Comment: If you are having 2 scopes than pass it separately `https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/files.read https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/files.write openid offline_access`

Comment: Modify your code like `public static readonly string[] Scopes = { "https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/files.read", "https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/files.write", };`

Comment: thank you, that fixed that. however I am still not returned a displayname and a userId. are they needed to access the db? because right now it says "Missing from token response". Token now is set to a value... and if I pass that into my functions, i get "Unexptected character encounrterd while pasing value : <. So I am assuming that is because I dont have all the data on my token yet maybe...

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217327/how-do-i-add-more-scopes-in-azure-b2c-user-flow/76224493#76224493