# Azure AD B2C UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication - Can't find Refresh Token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, .net-4.6.2

Got a somewhat convoluted and outdated workflow that we're trying to "somewhat" modernize. We are using a very old set of code (.NET 4.6.2), and are migrating an Azure AD B2C ROPC flow to an Authorization Code flow. We have the basic setup working - we capture the auth endpoint using `IAppBuilder.Map`, and then use `IAppBuilder.Run` to call `Authentication.Challenge` with the specified auth type.

In terms of the auth provider registration, we use `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`, with the following options:

```
AuthenticationType = AuthenticationType.Storefront,
ClientId = clientId,
Authority = authority,
SignInAsAuthenticationType = AuthenticationType.Storefront,
Scope = OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId,
ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.CodeIdToken,
PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/",
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    NameClaimType = "name",
},
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
    context.HandleResponse();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    RedirectToIdentityProvider = RedirectToSameDomain,
    SecurityTokenValidated = OnOrgUserSecurityTokenValidated,
    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnOrgAuthorizationCodeReceived
}
```

This works perfectly for getting the browser to redirect the user to Azure AD B2C, and then capturing the response with the `SecurityTokenValidated` callback. The problem is that in that response, the refresh token is always missing. We've tried several different places:

- `AuthenticationTicket.Properties.AllowRefresh` is always `false`, despite setting `AuthenticationProperties.AllowRefresh` to `true` during the `Authentication.Challenge` step
- `ProtocolMessage.AccessToken` contains a valid access token, however `ProtocolMessage.RefreshToken` is always `null`
- Both of the above hold true regardless of whether we look at `SecurityTokenValidated` or at `AuthorizationCodeReceived`

On top of all of the above, there's one more question which we're unsure about. Currently we use ROPC to refresh the access token. Will that work even if we use the Authorization Code flow for signing in?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Going to mark the answer from Rukmini (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76578895/1289046) as correct, but I wanted to elaborate a bit on the specific steps I needed to take, to get this working.

First things first - in terms of the setup info for what gets sent over to Azure AD B2C, the first `authorize` call is sent using `scope=openid` and `response_type=code id_token`. I then hook into the `SecurityTokenValidated` message that Azure AD B2C sends back when authentication has occurred successfully.

In there, I modified the overall flow significantly. From the response I get from Azure AD B2C, I take only the `ProtocolMessage.Code` value, and I use that to make another call to Azure AD B2C. This time, though, I call it using `grant_type=authorization_code` and I set the `code` parameter to the aforementioned `ProtocolMessage.Code` value. I make this call using a `client_id` and `client_secret` registered in Azure AD B2C.

The response of this *second* call properly contains the `refresh_token`, alongside the `id_token` and an `expires_in` value for both tokens.

Last, but not least, I rewired the refresh token behaviour - as long as the `refresh_token` hasn't expired, I use it to get a new `id_token` if it has expired or will soon do so. If the `refresh_token` has expired, I log the user out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD B2C Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, I **generated access token using ROPC flow** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:openid 
username:admin@b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com
password:*****
grant_type:password
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

> **Note** that: To generate refresh token, the **`offline_access`** scope is required.

To generate the refresh token, grant **`offline_access`** API permission:

[image]

Now while generating the token, pass **`offline_access`** scope like below:

```json
scope:openid offline_access
```

[image]

**To get refresh token, modify the code like below:**

```cs
AuthenticationType = AuthenticationType.Storefront,
ClientId = clientId,
Authority = authority, SignInAsAuthenticationType = AuthenticationType.Storefront,
Scope = OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenId + "offline_access",
ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.CodeIdToken,
```

> On top of all of the above, there's one more question which we're unsure about. Currently we use ROPC to refresh the access token. Will that work even if we use the Authorization Code flow for signing in?

```json
https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signinsignup/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:xxxx
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:openid offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

**Yes**, you can use ROPC to refresh the access token even if Authorization Code flow is used for signing in.

I am able to **refresh the access token generated by authorization code and using refresh token of ROPC**:

[image]

Comment: Hey Rukmini, thanks for the detailed response! I tried modifying the code the way you suggested - the request URL is now /[policy]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[client_id]&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+offline_access&state=[state]&nonce=[nonce]&redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=1.0.40306.1554, so I think the scope part worked, but the ProtocolMessage.RefreshToken is still null. Note that I'm not signing in using ROPC - signin is done through authorization code. Is that causing a problem?

Comment: Even if you are trying to generate refresh token using auth code flow, you have to pass offline access as scope to get refresh token.

Comment: I see you are passing & response_type=code+id_token maybe this is causing issue and not showing up refresh token. As it generates only code and Id token.

Comment: Hey Rukmini, I am passing offline_access scope. Looking at the specifications at https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html, I don't see offline_access as a valid response_type parameter

Comment: Yes you have to pass offline access in the scope itself but the response_type parameter is causing issue

Comment: Check this https://community.auth0.com/t/get-refresh-token-with-implicit-flow-where-response-type-token/91090

Comment: That site is referencing the token response_type. I'm using the authorization code response_type. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1 indicates that the refresh token should be supported, however, it also seems to indicate that I may need to make a second request against the /token endpoint to get it? Not sure if that applies for AADB2C specifically?

Comment: Check this for Authorization code flow in detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565926/azure-ad-b2c-after-mobile-log-in-the-token-returned-does-not-include-an-access/76570868#76570868

Comment: So, yeah - that question seems to confirm my hypothesis. The authorize endpoint returns an access code and the id_token, but it does not return the refresh_token. To get the refresh_token, I need to use the token endpoint with the access code. I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @SPT - haven't had a chance to test this yet, which is why I haven't marked it as solution. Will be doing so soon.